# How to get Thumbnail texture/image of a video in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a video gallery App for Gear VR and I have a video file stored in device storage lets say at :

```
string url = Application.persistentDataPath + "/video.mp4"
```

Is there a way to extract a thumbnail texture or preview image to display in UI for this video file.

[image: Just like Samsung Gallery App in Oculus Home VR]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: IU don't know if this would work but did you try calling www.texture? That should get the first frame... Maybe? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for some example in Oculus SDK package for Unity, I think they had some solution for that, but I am not sure.

However if you have a little bit more time for that you can write your own native plugin which will return selected thumbnail as an output.
To do that you will need to use function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                         getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri,
                         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                         (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

And then follow the [tutorial](http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/creating-a-native-android-plugin-for-unity3d/) about building the library.